# how to open a link in browser - Vue Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, vue.js, url, native

There is practically no information about this. I'm trying to use the Linking component from react-native, but there is very little information about using react native components, and I'm not sure if I'm using it right...

Here is what I have in template:

```html
<nb-button :on-press="loadInBrowser">
    <nb-text class="source"> Test hyperlink </nb-text>
</nb-button>
```

And here is in script:

```js
import Linking from "react-native";
export default {
    components: {
        Linking
    },
    //data(),
    methods: {
        loadInBrowser: function () {
          Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com");
        },
    },
}
```

But is not working, I'm getting this error:

```
"TypeError: _reactNative.default.openURL is not a function. (In '_reactNative.default.openURL("https://www.google.com")', '_reactNative.default.openURL' is undefined)
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
Linking.Linking.openURL("https://www.google.com");
```

Comment: Please [edit] your answer and explain what this code does, for more clarification. Read [answer] and take the [tour] to learn how this site works.